# Is it good practice to bind image paths from the view model

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am building a large Xamarin.Forms application using the MVVM design pattern and we are having some speed issues. There is a lot of tweaks we can do to speed this up.

I don't think this would make a major difference, but we are unnecessarily binding paths from the ViewModel for images throughout the app. I mean, it's easier to update images from the ViewModel rather then going through all the UI code. But other than that is there any reason why we would be doing this?

Comment: If I understand the issue correctly, you're including literal paths to images in the application? Theoretically, for good practice, you'll want to make them more configurable. Something that resolves the paths programmatically, or having configuration options. It's probably not a big deal either way, but the more generic and centralized you can make things the better. From time to time, on larger projects it might be a bit laborious to dig through tightly wound code. Again, not a huge deal either way though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the binding on your `ViewModel` to update the image `Source` on certain conditions then I'd say leave it the way it is. Otherwise, I'd directly set the `Source` in .xaml or .cs because each additional binding isn't very cost efficient.

Also, if you are having performance issues I'd check out the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/performance) on various ways to speed up your application. Those alone might be enough to improve performance that you wouldn't need to remove the extra bindings.

Comment: Thanks Nick. The docs is what made me raise the question with the unnecessary bindings bits. We aren't updating the image source for the bindings, they are just there for no reason. I will probably remove them then... cheers.

Comment: It definitely wouldn't hurt, especially with Forms, it's typically a combination of several small changes that will start to make a noticeable difference in performance.